# how to do ridge regression with log-link in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I want to do a ridge regression in R by using `glmnet` or `lm.ridge`.

I need to do this regression with `log(Y)`

```
cost ~ size + weight ⇒ log(cost) ~ size + weight
```

However, I found that there is no link like `glm` for `glmnet` or `lm.ridge`.

Any ideas for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *alpha* input parameter (with 0 value) for the `?glmnet` function. As the documentation says:

> alpha=1 is the lasso penalty, and alpha=0 the ridge penalty.

Try something like the following:

```
glmnet(x=cbind(size, weight), y=log(cost), alpha=0, family='gaussian')
```

or may be with *poission regression*

```
glmnet(x=cbind(size, weight), y=cost, alpha=0, family='poission')
```

If your input data is not too huge, you can calculate the learnt weights by ridge regression from the training data directly by using the formula `solve(t(X)%*%X + λ*I)%*%(t(X)%*%y)`, where *X* is your input variables matrix, *y* is response variable and *I* is the identity matrix, you can learn the best value of the lambda parameter using *cross-validation* from a *held-out* dataset.

Comment: Thank you,sandipan, i will try these.